# How to enable rotating images to load and display automatically

Tags: android, image, onitemclicklistener

I am trying to enable the rotating image to load and display automatically when the user access into a particular property name.

Currently, I am only able to display the rotating image when the user clicks on the image thumbnail after accessing the property name.

If the user doesn't click on the image thumbnail, the user will only witness the circular progress bar.

Hence, how to allow the image to be loaded and displayed immediately after user has access the property name without selecting the thumbnail image?

**Code**

```
if (panoSize > 0) {
        g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery01);
        g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter());
        int pad = 15;
        g.setSpacing(1);
        g.setUnselectedAlpha(255);
        g.setPadding(pad, 10, pad, pad);
        g.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                photo360Pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                img_id = position+1;
                setImageShade(position);
                captionText.setText(caption[position]);

                Log.i("PropertyPanoramaActvity:if(panoSize>0)","******webView.loadUrl******"
                +getString(R.string.app_360_domain)+getString(R.string.app_360_property)
                +(getIntent().getIntExtra("propertyId", 0))+getString(R.string.app_360_directory)
                +(img_id)+getString(R.string.app_360_index));

                webView.loadUrl(String.format(getString(R.string.app_360_domain)
                        +getString(R.string.app_360_property)+(getIntent().getIntExtra("propertyId", 0))
                        +getString(R.string.app_360_directory)+img_id
                        +getString(R.string.app_360_index)));
            }
        });
    }
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:background="@color/transparent">
<include layout="@layout/header" />
<include layout="@layout/property_nav" />
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@color/transparent">
    <include layout="@layout/property_share" />
</RelativeLayout>
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:layout_weight="4" android:orientation="vertical">
    <WebView android:id="@+id/webview01" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"></WebView>
    <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/photo360Pb" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"  />
</FrameLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/caption"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />

<Gallery android:id="@+id/gallery01" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<include layout="@layout/mainmenu" />
```

Comment: You basically want  image to do what circular progressbar does?

Comment: @Tushar the circular progressbar only shows that the image is being loaded, but the progress bar is suppose to disappear when the image is loaded. At this moment, I would want the image to load and display automatically without user having to select the thumbnail image

Comment: Then set  `photo360Pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);` once you have got the image.

Comment: @Tushar  the circular progress bar will disappear when the image is loaded, hence that is not the issue. The issue, is that I want the image to load automatically after I have entered property name A without having to select the thumbnail image shown in that activity

Comment: Do you press any key after entering that property? If no then you'll have to use `TextWatcher` to check what is entered and you can load image `onTextChanged()` method of TextWatcher.

Comment: @Tushar what do you mean? and where do i add TextWatcher? And why do I need TextWatcher to notify me of the changes made?

Comment: Check out the [tutorial](http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/06/using-textwatcher-in-android.html) for TextWatcher.

Comment: TextWatcher is a way of doing what you want to do, **OR** you can use simple condition `if(!(editText.getText()==null || editText.getText().toString().equals("")))` then load the image.

Comment: @Tushar But in this case shouldnt it be for textView?

Comment: Whatever it is, you can use this condition to check if it got some value or not.

Comment: @Tushar, it has got values if you are referring to the image that has been called. It is logged in the logcat and by referencing to the img_id and the img_position, it is correct. Is that what you are referring to when you are talking about values?

Comment: @Tushar its okay, I have got it settled. Thanks for your input

Comment: I was talking about the name value you were talking about. What did you do to make it work?

Comment: @Tushar I added `webView.loadUrl(String.format(getString(R.string.app_360_domain)
                        +getString(R.string.app_360_property)+(getIntent().getIntExtra("propertyId", 0))
                        +getString(R.string.app_360_directory)+img_id
                        +getString(R.string.app_360_index)));`  in to the `protected void onPostExecute(Long result)`  and the images showed automatically after each loading